# MacOS High Sierra - Creating a window at the same level as the virtual accessibility keyboard & notifications

Tags: macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to create a window that is on the same level as the accessibility keyboard and notifications on High Sierra. My desired result is to get a window that will appear above all other windows, including the screensaver and lock screen.

In el cap/sierra I was able to use `window.level = NSWindow.Level(Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow)))` but now in High Sierra my code does not work and I cannot see my window over the screensaver or lock screen.

After some experimenting I noticed that notifications and the accessibility keyboard DO show up over the lock screen/screensaver and was wondering if it is possible to create a window on the same level.

I've included two pictures, [one of the lock screen showing both the keyboard/notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3X3f.jpg). The second image shows what happens when I [transition from one window to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Idt.png) - my demo window stays on the desktop but the keyboard/notification is shown above the desktops and transitions over the dividing bar from one to another.

Anyone know of a way I can create this type of behavior in my window?

Comment: Any luck finding solution to this problem? I want to display customised login screen. and am having the same issue.